# Design blog schema with author information in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have some blogs, which have title, body, etc. Each blog  document will have `author` attribute, which contains author information.

```js
{
  title:"..",
  body:"...",
  authorId:"1"
}
```

I have a `users` collection, which have the following schema.

```js
{
  _id:"1",
  name:"..",
  imageUrl:".."
}
```

At the time of DB query, i would like to get all blogs with it's author information.

In the response, i would like to get the following...

```js
[
    {
        _id:"blog1",
        title:"..",
        body:"..",
        author:{
            _id:"...",
            name:"..",
            imageUrl:"..."
        }
    },
    {
        _id:"blog2",
        title:"..",
        body:"..",
        author:{
            _id:"...",
            name:"..",
            imageUrl:"..."
        }
    }
]
```

## Solution 1

At the time of blog creation, i can save author information each `blog` document.

**Drawbacks**

The author information will be duplicated everywhere.

## Solution 2

I can use `ref` of mongodb.

```js
db.blogs.insert({_id:1,title:"Blog",body:"...",author:{"$ref":"users","$id":"1"}});
```

```js
db.blogs.aggregate([{"$lookup":{"from":"users","localField":"author.$id","foreignField":"_id","as":"user"}}])
```

## The Problem

On my home page i want to display all blogs with it's user profile image.

> See below image

[image: blogs]

## Optimal

Which solution is efficient in terms of memory and speed?